# Get data from JSON, store in IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings, retrieve data when JSON is retrieved

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to do what the title says in Windows Phone 8 and here is how I go about it:

```
private async void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    settings.Add("listofCurrency", await CurrencyHelpers.getJsonCurrency());
}
```

In CurrencyHelpers:

```
    public async static Task<Dictionary<string, double>> getJsonCurrency()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        string jsonResult = await client.GetStringAsync("http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=xxxxxxx");

        JSONCurrency jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONCurrency>(jsonResult);

        Dictionary<string, double> currencyCollection = new Dictionary<string, double>();

        currencyCollection = jsonData.Rates;

        return currencyCollection;

    }
```

When the MainPage loads, I immediately call another method from CurrencyHelpers:

```
    public static KeyValuePair<double, double> getStorageCurrencyPairRates(string firstCurrency, string secondCurrency)
    {
        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        double firstCurrencyRate = 1;
        double secondCurrencyRate = 1;

        Dictionary<string, double> currencyCollection = new Dictionary<string,double>();

        //needs some code here to check if "listofCurrency" already has JSONData stored in it.

        settings.TryGetValue<Dictionary<string,double>>("listofCurrency", out currencyCollection);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> pair in currencyCollection)
        {
            if (pair.Key == firstCurrency)
            {
                firstCurrencyRate = pair.Value;
            }

            else if (pair.Key == secondCurrency)
            {
                secondCurrencyRate = pair.Value;
            }
         }

        return new KeyValuePair<double, double>(firstCurrencyRate, secondCurrencyRate);          
    }
}
```

The idea is that I want to store my JSON data to storage, then immediately retrieve it when it is available, any ideas? Help is much appreciated!

Comment: I tried using
    while(!settings.Contains("listofCurrency")
    
but the thread just cycles through the while loop and the awaited method to get the JSON data never completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are thinking with await and async is correct but you destroyed its concept by calling another method just when the page loads. What Wilfred Wee said is also wrong.

The correct way would be to declare an event handler in your App.xamls.cs like this:

`public event EventHandler<bool> SettingsReady;`

Then change your Application_Launching() method to the following:

```
private async void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    settings.Add("listofCurrency", await CurrencyHelpers.getJsonCurrency());

    if (SettingsReady!= null)
        SettingsReady(this, true);
}
```

And now in your MainPage.xaml.cs (CONSTRUCTOR - NOT WHEN LOADED) declare the call back function to be called when the data will actually be ready:

```
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Call back functions
        App.SettingsReady += App_SettingsReady;
    }

    void App_SettingsReady(object sender, bool e)
    {
        // Here call your function for further data processing
        getStorageCurrencyPairRates();
    }
```

Comment: Hi @George, thanks a lot for the help! I had to make the event static but otherwise everything was perfect. Thanks again.